# Getting GML features with OpenLayers from Spanish Cadaster fails

Tags: openlayers, wfs, gml

I'm trying to paint parcels retrieved from Spanish land register by their API (as described [here](https://www.catastro.minhap.es/webinspire/documentos/inspire-cp-WFS.pdf), PDF Spanish only!). It's an WFS service (complying INSPIRE) and offers the information as GML versión 3.2.1 files.

Here an example response (using this [call](http://ovc.catastro.meh.es/INSPIRE/wfsCP.aspx?service=wfs&version=2&request=getfeature&STOREDQUERIE_ID=GetParcel&refcat=3662001TF3136S&srsname=EPSG::25830)) to retrieve parcels by their cadaster reference:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!--Parcela Catastral de la D.G. del Catastro.-->
<!--La precisión es la que corresponde nominalmente a la escala de captura de la cartografía-->
<FeatureCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:cp="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0 http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0/CadastralParcels.xsd" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" timeStamp="2022-08-30T19:29:52" numberMatched="1" numberReturned="1">
  <member>
    <cp:CadastralParcel gml:id="ES.SDGC.CP.3662001TF3136S">
      <cp:areaValue uom="m2">3814</cp:areaValue>
      <cp:beginLifespanVersion>2021-06-09T00:00:00</cp:beginLifespanVersion>
      <cp:endLifespanVersion xsi:nil="true" nilReason="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/codelist/VoidReasonValue/Unpopulated"></cp:endLifespanVersion>
      <cp:geometry>
        <gml:MultiSurface gml:id="MultiSurface_ES.SDGC.CP.3662001TF3136S" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/25830">
          <gml:surfaceMember>
            <gml:Surface gml:id="Surface_ES.SDGC.CP.3662001TF3136S.1" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/25830">
              <gml:patches>
                <gml:PolygonPatch>
                <gml:exterior>
                    <gml:LinearRing>
                      <gml:posList srsDimension="2" count="68">233565.81 4016077.37 233581.88 4016079.67 233582.39 4016079.64 233582.41 4016079.64 233582.93 4016079.61 233582.95 4016079.79 233584.21 4016095.89 233590.37 4016086.81 233608.95 4016076.64 233622.4 4016059.04 233634.4 4016039.96 233635.42 4016038.33 233637.7 4016034.42 233639.69 4016030.68 233639.92 4016030.24 233641.36 4016028.14 233641.81 4016027.47 233643.7 4016024.87 233644.86 4016023.27 233646.95 4016020.39 233645.01 4016006.5 233655.45 4015995.96 233655.14 4015995.64 233651.48 4015991.83 233650.44 4015990.75 233648.45 4015992.4 233640.59 4015999.13 233639.85 4015999.81 233639.12 4016000.48 233637.69 4016001.88 233636.31 4016003.33 233634.97 4016004.81 233633.68 4016006.34 233633.17 4016006.97 233628.43 4016014.77 233626.25 4016018.35 233623.19 4016023.38 233623.04 4016023.63 233619.94 4016026.88 233615.37 4016031.67 233614.08 4016033.01 233613.46 4016033.66 233610.82 4016035.98 233602.71 4016043.12 233600.17 4016045.28 233596.47 4016048.66 233591.23 4016053.38 233589.87 4016052.05 233584.62 4016052.25 233584.33 4016052.26 233581.97 4016049.04 233578.37 4016045.27 233576.52 4016043.93 233574.11 4016042.19 233569.38 4016039.9 233564.32 4016038.46 233559.09 4016037.93 233553.84 4016038.31 233548.39 4016039.75 233543.94 4016041.75 233537.63 4016037.54 233535.81 4016033.81 233535.16 4016033.58 233530.41 4016023.48 233532.15 4016035.61 233543.76 4016066.93 233552.15 4016070.9 233565.81 4016077.37</gml:posList>
                    </gml:LinearRing>
                </gml:exterior>
                </gml:PolygonPatch>
              </gml:patches>
            </gml:Surface>
          </gml:surfaceMember>
        </gml:MultiSurface>
      </cp:geometry>
      <cp:inspireId>
        <Identifier xmlns="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/base/3.3">
          <localId>3662001TF3136S</localId>
          <namespace>ES.SDGC.CP</namespace>
        </Identifier>
      </cp:inspireId>
      <cp:label>01</cp:label>
      <cp:nationalCadastralReference>3662001TF3136S</cp:nationalCadastralReference>
      <cp:referencePoint>
        <gml:Point gml:id="ReferencePoint_ES.SDGC.CP.3662001TF3136S" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/25830"> 
          <gml:pos>233584.35 4016065.6</gml:pos>
        </gml:Point>
      </cp:referencePoint>
    </cp:CadastralParcel>
  </member>
</FeatureCollection>
```

Right now I manually parse the XML file and make a vector feature, but would be more elegant to make the feature from `GML32` format. To do so, I tried to get the parcel geometry from GML, but without success:

```js
const parser = new ol.format.GML32({
    featureNS: 'http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp',
    featureType: 'CadastralParcel'
});
console.log(parser.readFeature(wfsCPxml));
```

I also tried using WFS format, but same null result (after changing manually `surfaceMember` to `featureMember` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10700)):

```js
const wfs = new ol.format.WFS({
  gmlFormat: new ol.format.GML32({
    featureNS: 'http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp',
    featureType: 'CadastralParcel'
  })
});
console.log(parser.readFeature(wfsCPfeaturexml));
```

Here is the related [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geraldo/Lnh42mos/), any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: surprised your example request works, as it doesn't follow WFS syntax.  It should be: `http://ovc.catastro.meh.es/INSPIRE/wfsCP.aspx?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&STOREDQUERY_ID=GetParcel&REFCAT=3662001TF3136S&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25830`

Comment: I assume the answer as to why `GML 3.2.1 can't be parsed by ol.format.GML32` doesn't work for you will be based on the fact that [cp:CadastralParcel](https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0/CadastralParcels.xsd) is a complex feature, and OpenLayers is expecting simple features

Comment: The example request is copied from the docs and does work (it had an typo so). I don't know which map server they are using, [GetCapabilities](http://ovc.catastro.meh.es/INSPIRE/wfsCP.aspx?service=WFS&Version=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities) doesn't give any hint on that. Reading the docs on GML32 it's not clear to me if complex features aren't supported (I just opened an [issue](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14094) on that).